# Is it possible to execute query independently on each partition?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a quite complex query, that takes a lot of time to finish. However, table has partitions and in fact result would be ok if this query is executed independently on each partition. This way ordering would be limited to smaller portions of data, which is fine for me. Is it possible to execute such query independently on each partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is create a query selecting a specific partition and use an union all between the queries to consolidate the results. I am not sure what Hive version you are using, but make sure that you set the following property

```
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
```

Query example

```
select sum(a) from table1 where partition1='a'
union all
select sum(a) from table1 where partition1='b'
union all
select sum(a) from table1 where partition1='c';
```

that you trigger 3 independent stages in parallel and 1 stage to consolidate the results. You can validate this using

```
explain
select sum(a) from table1 where partition1='a'
union all
select sum(a) from table1 where partition1='b'
union all
select sum(a) from table1 where partition1='c';
```

you should see 3 stage in parallel and 1 stage depending on the other 3.

Comment: Thanks. It is a pity that this could not be done automatically. My queries are quite long and I have many partitions, so it would not be very convenient to do that this way, but it is better than nothing,

Comment: is not good but it is an option, I have faced this before and usually I ended creating quickly a script to generate the query for me. good luck!